# Can't initialize cropper.js (Uncaught TypeError: image.cropper is not a function at FileReader.oFReader.onload)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cropper, cropperjs

I'm using cropper.js and when I try to initialize, i get the error `Uncaught TypeError: image.cropper is not a function at FileReader.oFReader.onload`. I have copied the code from one last project I did, and in that project it works normally.

I have tried both of cropper and cropper.js and nothing works.
And I inport the cropper to html like this the the head of the document.

```html
<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/cropperjs/dist/cropper.js"></script>
<link href="node_modules/cropperjs/dist/cropper.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="node_modules/jquery-cropper/dist/jquery-cropper.js"></script>
```

My form is like this with the other fields in it.

```html
<form action="backend/send.php" method="post">
   ...(more html with the other fields)
   <p>Imagem Cabeçalho:<br>
      <label class="form-filebutton">Carregar Imagem
         <input type="file" id="imagem" name="imagem" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/JPEG, image/jpeg2000, image/jpg, image/gif">
      </label>
   </p>
   ...(more html with the other fields)
</form>
```

The image should appear here.

```html
<div class="div-preview hidden">
   <img class="img-preview" id="img-preview">
   ...(more html with buttons to edit the image)
</div>
```

Here is what I do to initialize Cropper.

```
$(function() {
   var image = $("#img-preview"); //where the image should appear
   //Initialize cropper when image is loaded in the form
   $("input:file").change(function() {
      $(".div-preview").removeClass("hidden"); //show the elements

      var oFReader = new FileReader();

      oFReader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
      oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
         image.cropper("destroy"); //In case I change the image
         image.attr("src", this.result); 
         image.cropper({
            aspectRatio: 1 / 1,
            viewMode: 1,
            toggleDragModeOnDblclick: false,
            dragMode: "move",
            crop: function(e) {}
         });
      };
   });
   ...(more jQuery and JavaScript to control the buttons)
});
```

I'm expecting to open the cropper but I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: image.cropper is not a function at FileReader.oFReader.onload` in the first cropper (`image.cropper("destroy");`).

Answer (score 0):

to fix it I just moved the following code to the body of my page.

```html
<script src="node_modules/cropperjs/dist/cropper.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/jquery-cropper/dist/jquery-cropper.js"></script>
```